# Getting smallest element from Binary Search Tree but ignoring 0

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I have managed to get the smallest from BST. But what I wanted is to get the smallest element from BST ignoring the 0 value. For example:

I have these values in my BST:

1.3 , 5.4 ,6.7, 1.5, 0

I need the function to return 1.3 but not 0.

These are my codes :

```
 template <class elemType>
elemType binaryTreeType<elemType>::find_min(nodeType<elemType> *p) const
{

    elemType value = p->info;

    nodeType<elemType> *left_node = p->lLink;
    if (left_node != NULL)
    {
        elemType left_value = find_min(left_node);
        if (left_value < value && left_value != 0)
            value = left_value;

    }

    nodeType<elemType> *right_node = p->rLink;
    if (right_node != NULL)
    {

        elemType right_value = find_min(right_node);
        if (right_value < value && right_value != 0)
            value = right_value;

    }

    return value;
}
```

Comment: In-order traversal of BST visits elements in order, from smallest to largest. Perform this traversal and stop at the first non-zero element.

Comment: What is your question? Also, your function seems to have linear complexity instead of logarithmic complexity (or at least, linear in the depth, not in the size of the BST), you should only explore the right node if the current node contains the value 0 (otherwise, the current value is an acceptable value which is smaller than any value in its right sub-tree)

Comment: Also, what is your function supposed to return if no such element exists? (if the tree is empty or only contains 0)

Answer (score 0):

That is how i would do it (even though i still have problems with the function definition if elemType isn't an arithmetic, or if, as stated in one of my comments, the tree is empty)

```
/* is elemType always an arithmetic type? your question implies that
 * you can compare a variable of type elemType to 0
 */
template <class elemType>
elemType binaryTreeType<elemType>::find_min(nodeType<elemType> *p) const
{
  nodeType<elemType>* minNode = nullptr;
  nodeType<elemType>* currentNode = p;
  elemType value = p->info;
  while(currentNode)
  {
    if(currentNode->info != 0)
    {
      minNode = currentNode;
      currentNode = currentNode->left;
    }
    else
      currentNode = currentNode->left?currentNode->left:currentNode->right;
      /* if you accept a tree with several identical values,
       * this line is incorrect (the update of minNode may also be,
       * depending on which correction you choose)
       */
  }
  if(!currentNode)
  {
    // we have a problem here: there is no non-0 element in the tree!
    return 0; // is that the behaviour you want?
  }
  return minNode->info();
}
```

Also note that if the tree can store the same values several times, that function might be incorrect if the root contains 0 and all the nodes in its left subtree contains 0, in which case i see three solutions:
- either write a function with linear complexity in the tree's size
- add a boolean in each node stating whether one of its child contains a non-0 node, then decide each subtree to explore with the following rule: if left exists and contains at least a non-0 node, explore left, otherwise explore right (you can stop the computation if left exists and doesn't contains at least a non-0 node and the minimum node isn't null)
- ensure that each left child is *strictly* smaller than its parent